# Creates a series of folders from a given starting date

Tags: python

I made this python script to create dated folders within a directory. This is my first practical automation project and I don't want to cement any bad habits so I was wondering if there is anything I can improve in the code I have written here. Any feedback will be appreciated!

The main challenge I had was to account for months with different day ranges, and then to reset the counts properly for all the variables. I feel like this is more complicated than it probably needs to be but I don't know if there are some python libraries I am unaware of that could help simplify it more.

I thought about having a predefined end date as well but that would require the user to open up a calendar and find 2 dates. I figured by just asking for a start date and how many folders they want, I could make things simpler for the end user but I'm not even sure that that is actually the case.

I also don't know if I've used classes correctly here. At first I had everything thrown into the while statement. I also considered using a for loop instead of while but went with while instead. Again, this is my first real project so any help with other decisions I could have made will be appreciated!

```
import os
import pathlib

directory = "/Users/myName/Box Sync/SAFAC/Budget Requests/2020-2021/Weekly/"

# directory = input("Enter the path where you would like to create files: ")
date = input("Enter the starting date in mm-dd-yyyy format: ")
period = int(input("Enter the period between each date folder: "))
instances = int(input("How many folders do you want? "))

Folders = []

arguments = date.split("-")
dayArgument = arguments[1]
monthArgument = arguments[0]
yearArgument = arguments[2]
init = instances - instances
elapse = period - period
seperator = "-"

month = int(monthArgument)
day = int(dayArgument) + int(elapse)

def make_directories(input_list):
    for folderName in input_list:
        dirpath = os.path.join(directory, folderName[0:],'Documentation')
        try:
            os.makedirs(dirpath)
        except FileExistsError:
            print('Directory {} already exists'.format(dirpath))
        else:
            print('Directory {} created'.format(dirpath))

def add_folder_to_list(month,day,year,extra):
    full_name_constructor = (month,day,year,extra)
    # full_name_constructor = (str(month),str('0'+str(day)),yearArgument,"Budgets")
    fullName = seperator.join(full_name_constructor)
    Folders.append(fullName)

def format_and_append_folder_name():
    if day < 10 and month >= 10:
        add_folder_to_list(str(month),str('0'+str(day)),yearArgument,"Budgets")
    elif day >= 10 and month < 10:
        add_folder_to_list(str('0'+str(month)),str(day),yearArgument,"Budgets")
    elif day < 10 and month < 10:
        add_folder_to_list(str('0'+str(month)),str('0'+str(day)),yearArgument,"Budgets")
    else:
        add_folder_to_list(str(month),str(day),yearArgument,"Budgets")

def check_month():
    global maxDays 
    if (month % 2 ) == 0 and month != 2 : # if even but not February
        maxDays = 30
    elif month == 2 :
        maxDays = 28 #if February
    else :
        maxDays = 31 # if odd


while init < instances :
    check_month()
    format_and_append_folder_name()
    make_directories(Folders)
    # print(Folders[init])            # for debugging

    init += 1
    elapse += period
    day = int(dayArgument) + int(elapse)

    if day > maxDays :
            month += 1
            day -= maxDays                  # reset days
            dayArgument = day               # recalibrate the new zero point for the day to be the date in the new month
            elapse = 0                      # recalibrate elapse point to 0 so it can reiterate the period again
```

Comment: Excellent question, particularly for a newcomer to the site.

Answer (score 3):

OK let's look at your code.

### Unused Imports

`pathlib` was imported but I don't see any use of it in the codebase, I understand that this might be as a result of testing out approaches to a problem. `pylint` can help mitigate this by catching unused modules. It also catches some PEP guidelines which your code breaks.

### Avoid Globals

You have lots of global variables. A common approach whenever you want to use a global is asking yourself some questions; "How do I express myself with code whilst avoiding this global variable". When in doubt,  prefer objects that holds `state` to global variables.

### Code Review

On first glance,  I can see you are manually parsing dates. This doesn't look good, you introduce bugs when reinventing the wheel. Right now,  your code contains a bug,  it accepts invalid dates,  I can easily create a date like this
`date = "12-03-202022"`
The above code generates no error, this can be disastrous.
A common alternative is using python  `datetime` module. This simplify everything, we can move the dates by periods easily,  creating directories becomes quite easy.

NOTE: datetime  module checks for invalid dates.

A simple way of creating a date from a string is given as

```
from datetime  import datetime
date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d/%m/%y")
```

This simple line of code simplifies everything,  the full code can then be written as

```
"""Directory creating program"""

import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def next_date(date, period):
    """Increase the date by timedelta
        date: datetime object
        period: timedelta to increase our date by
    """
    new_date = date + timedelta(days=period)
    return '/'.join((str(new_date.day), str(new_date.month), str(new_date.year))), new_date

def make_directories(home_dir, start_date, instances, period):
    """Create sub directories in the home_dir

        home_dir: base directory
        start_date: date to append to directories created
        instances: number of directories to create
        period: difference between two dates
    """
    date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d/%m/%y")

    for i in range(instances):
        start_date = start_date.replace('/', '-')
        dirpath = os.path.join(directory, start_date,'Documentation')
        try:
            os.makedirs(dirpath)
        except FileExistsError:
            print('Directory {} already exists'.format(dirpath))
        else:
            print('Directory {} created'.format(dirpath))

        start_date, date = next_date(date, period)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    directory = "/Users/myName/Box Sync/SAFAC/Budget Requests/2020-2021/Weekly/"
    make_directories(directory, '3/1/20', 10, 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

### Hard-coded paths

It looks like you started off asking for this:

```
directory = input("Enter the path where you would like to create files: ")
```

but then changed your mind:

```
directory = "/Users/myName/Box Sync/SAFAC/Budget Requests/2020-2021/Weekly/"
```

The latter style of hard-coded directories should be avoided. Accept the directory via `input`, or (more likely) via `argparse`.

### Unit specificity

```
Enter the period between each date folder
```

is not specific enough. Period in days, months, years? A combined timedelta format? Based on your code it looks like days, but your prompt should specify.

### Datetime parsing

Don't do `split`-based date parsing like this:

```
dayArgument = arguments[1]
monthArgument = arguments[0]
yearArgument = arguments[2]
```

Instead, call into one of the parsing routines in [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime). Beyond that, `mm-dd-yyyy` is both non-standard and non-sortable. Strongly consider using `yyyy-mm-dd` instead.

Likewise, rather than

```
def add_folder_to_list(month,day,year,extra):
    full_name_constructor = (month,day,year,extra)
    # full_name_constructor = (str(month),str('0'+str(day)),yearArgument,"Budgets")
    fullName = seperator.join(full_name_constructor)
```

just use the built-in `datetime` format routines.

### Pathlib

You import it, but you don't use it here:

```
    dirpath = os.path.join(directory, folderName[0:],'Documentation')
```

Best to replace your `join` with a `/` operator on a `Path` instance.

### Spelling

`seperator` -> `separator`

Answer (score 2):

#### Bugs

There are a few (potential) bugs in you program: `check_month()` doesn't handle leap years and the code doesn't handle roll over at the end of a year.

#### `datetime`

Using `datetime` from the standard library can fix these bugs and simplify the code.  `datetime.date()` provides methods for parsing and formating date strings.  And `datetime.timedelta()` for adding an interval or period to a date.

Using the library, your code can be simplified to something like:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from pathlib import Path

template = input(f"Enter a directory template (use DD for day, MM for month, YYYY for year): ")
template = template.replace('YYYY', '{0:%Y}').replace('MM', '{0:%m}').replace('DD', '{0:%d}')

start = input(f"Enter a start date (yyyy-mm-dd): ")
current_date = date.fromisoformat(start)

period = input("Enter the number of days between each date folder: ")
period = timedelta(days=int(period))

count = int(input(f"Enter the number of folders to create: "))
        
for _ in range(count):
    path = Path(template.format(current_date))

    try:
        path.mkdir(parents=True)

    except FileExistsError:
        print(f'Directory {path} already exists.')

    else:
        print(f'Directory {path} created.')
    
    current_date += period
```

Using a template provides some flexibility in telling the code what directories to create.  The template gets turned into a format string by replacing codes in the template with formatting codes for the components of a date.  For example, 'YYYY' in the template gets replaced with '{0:%Y}'.  When the format string is used to format a date, the `{0:%Y}` gets replaced with the 4-digit year.  'DD' and 'MM' are use for the day and month respectively.  Letting the user enter a code like 'YYYY' and then replacing it with the format code is just to sanitize the user input.

The `date.fromisoformat()` parses a date in the YYYY-MM-DD format and returns a date object. If you really need to use DD-MM-YYYY format, also import `datetime` from the `datetime` library and use `start = datetime.strptime(start, "%d-%m-%Y").date()`.

I prefer using `pathlib`, so I used that in the code.  `os.path` would work just as well.

#### User experience (UX)

With some additional effort, the user experience can be improved.  For example, default values can be provided for some inputs.  As another, a stop date can be used instead of a number of periods (quick: how many weeks are there between 2021-01-08 and 2021-08-01?).

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from pathlib import Path

DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = "/Users/myName/Box Sync/SAFAC/Budget Requests/2020-2021/Weekly/DD-MM-YYYY-Budgets/Documentation"
DEFAULT_START = dt.date.today()
DEFAULT_PERIOD = 7   # days
DEFAULT_COUNT = 1  # a str

print("Enter the following (defaults are in [])")

template = input(f"  Directory template (use DD for day, MM for month, YYYY for year)\n[{DEFAULT_TEMPLATE}]: ")
if template == '':
    template = DEFAULT_TEMPLATE
template = template.replace('YYYY', '{0:%Y}').replace('MM', '{0:%m}').replace('DD', '{0:%d}')

start = input(f"  Start date (yyyy-mm-dd) [{DEFAULT_START}]: ")
if start:
    date = dt.date.fromisoformat(start)
else:
    date = DEFAULT_START

period = input(f"  Number of days between each date folder [{DEFAULT_PERIOD}]: ")
if period == '':
    period = DEFAULT_PERIOD
period = dt.timedelta(days=int(period))

end = input(f"  Number of folders or a stop date (yyyy-mm-dd) [{DEFAULT_COUNT}]: ")
if end == '':
    end = date + period * DEFAULT_COUNT
    
elif '-' in end:
    end_date = dt.date.fromisoformat(end)
    
else:
    end_date = date + period * int(end)

    
while date < end_date:
    path = Path(template.format(date))
    
    try:
        path.mkdir(parents=True)

    except FileExistsError:
        print(f'Directory {path} already exists.')

    else:
        print(f'Directory {path} created.')

    date += period
```

In the code, the prompts include the default value in '[]'.  If the user just hits ENTER, the default values get used.  The code for determining the `end_date` uses the default number of periods if the user doesn't enter anything.  Otherwise, it checks to see if the user entered a date or a count and does the appropriate conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with most if not all the points made by other answers thus far so I won't rehash their answers.  Here are some additional points.

- Use type hints. They will save you (or the next person who has to look at this script) in the long run.
- Using Clean Code principles, break down responsibility into smaller functions.
- Check to see if the file that already exists is indeed a folder.

```py
# Trying to make a folder and catching the exception when it already exists 
# is a good idea except when the thing that already exists is a FILE not a FOLDER.
def make_directory(value: str):
    try:
        os.makedirs(value)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(value):
            pass
        else:
            raise
```

- Avoid unnecessary actions. Use `init = 0` instead of `init = instances - instances`
- `if day < 10 and month >= 10:` can be written as `if day < 10 <= month:`
- If you're using globals, it's a good sign you should create a class.